# Unable to import fabric.js in web-worker?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, fabricjs, web-worker

I am using webpack for a React.js application. I need to do a heavy work with fabric. So I tried to use web worker for that purpose.
I used worker-loader plugin for running web-worker. And my woker is working fine.
This is my worker file

```
var jsZip = require('jszip')
const PDFDocument = require('@react-pdf/pdfkit').default
const SVGtoPDF = require('svg-to-pdfkit')
const fabric = require('fabric')

self.onmessage = async ({ data: { canvasInfo } }) => {

    const canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('canvas', {
      width:1024,
      height: 1024,
      selection: false,
    })

    // Doing heavy work with fabric canvas fn()

    self.postMessage({
      message:"success"
    })
}
```

But I got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jsdom.JSDOM is not a constructor
    at Object../node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js (fabric.js:25)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:21)
    at web.worker.js:5
    at web.worker.bundle.worker.js:140722
    at web.worker.bundle.worker.js:140724
```

Is there anything I need to add in my webpack configuration to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

the web worker has maybe window undefined and is triggering the nodejs code path.
You should open an issue on the repo, and we should think of a fix. Fabricjs does use dom related methods that probably aren't available in a worker

Comment: I don't need to interact with the dom from the web worker. I just want to create one virtual canvas with fabric js do some works in web worker.  I am using the webworker because I don't want to affect the background task to the UI.

Comment: Is there is any method to define a virtual dom in webworker?